# Find the largest $n$ such that $\sqrt{n+60}+\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{m}$, for $\sqrt{m} \notin \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Possibly duplicated [but i think that it is slightly different.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003624/find-the-largest-possible-integer-n-such-that-sqrtn-sqrtn60-m-for-some)

This is from a math Olympiad in which I participated yesterday, and this is my solution:

$$\sqrt{n+60}+\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{m} \iff \sqrt{n+60} =\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}$$
$$n+60=m-2\sqrt{mn}+n \iff 2\sqrt{mn}=m-60$$

**Restriction $1$:**
Since $m-60\in \mathbb N \implies 2\sqrt{mn} \implies \sqrt{mn}\in \mathbb N$

**Restriction $2$:**
Furthermore $2\mid m-60$ And $2\mid 60 \implies 2\mid m$

$$\sqrt{n+60}+\sqrt{n}=\sqrt{m}\iff \sqrt{n}=\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n+60}$$
$$n=m-2\sqrt{mn+60m}+n+60$$
$$2\sqrt{mn+60m}=60+m$$
$$4mn+240m=3600+120m+m^2$$
**Restriction $3$:** By some basic algebra we get $m\mid 3600$

My method to solve this problem is to Check the even divisors of $3600$, By some long calculations i’ve found that the largest $m$ is $m=300$ Which implies that the largest $n$ is $n=48$.

And we can verify that by **restriction 1** because $\sqrt{mn}=\sqrt{300\cdot 48}=120\in \mathbb N$

The solution seems quite valid to me, my question is the statement ‘ $m=300$ Which implies that the largest $n$ is $n=48$’ valid? Because i cant prove that the largest $m$ gives the largest $n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(m_1,n_1)$ and $(m_2,n_2)$ be two pairs of solutions with $m_1>m_2$. It follows $\sqrt{m_1}>\sqrt{m_2}$ and so $\sqrt{n_1+60} + \sqrt{n_1} > \sqrt{n_2+60} + \sqrt{n_2}$. You can then use this to prove $n_1>n_2$ by contradiction.

Really what is happening is that the inverse of an increasing function is also increasing (here we have $f(x) = (\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+60})^2$ with the domain $[0,\infty)$) but this is probably more advanced that what you need.

Comment: Do you mean if i can prove that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+60}$ is an increasing function then if $a>b$ It follows that $$f(a)>f(b)$$. Which prove my statement ?

Comment: I forgot to square it, but what I wanted to say is that $f^{-1}(a) > f^{-1}(b)$. In any case you only need the first paragraph to solve your problem.